# gridview not updating when id click on update

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

### this is my code for updating gridview

> when click on update it id not updating and going back to its previous value but but delete option working properly

```
        Id = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblDealerId")).Text;
        Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDealer_Name")).Text;
        Address = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDealer_Address")).Text;
        City = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
        Pincode = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDealer_Pincode")).Text;

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_update_dealer", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Address;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = City;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_pincode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Pincode;

        //GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: in your database what is the datatype of this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@dealer_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Id;` can you show us..? also why are you casting the selected DataGridView.RowIndex as (Label) why not assign it based on that selected row and get the Id that way..?

Answer (score 0):

Your Label `lblDealerId` should also placed in `EditTemplate`:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDealerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
    //.. some other TexBoxes
</EditItemTemplate>
```